# Get application in attachBaseContext method in Activity

Tags: java, android

Currently I'm trying to implement localization in my app. So I'm using manual DI in application. MyApp class keeps container which is keeping LocaleManager (more info: https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/manual). So the main problem is that I can't get reference to my app class through getApplication() method, it gives me null pointer exception.
How could I get reference to MyApp class from activity's attachBaseContext method.
Here is my activity's attachBaseContext method:

```
 @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(((MyApp) getApplication()).appContainer.localeManager.setLocale(base));
    }
```

Here is received exception (P.S. AlgyrApp is MyApp class):

```
2021-11-27 19:45:41.109 20499-20499/tm.com.algyr E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: tm.com.algyr, PID: 20499
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{tm.com.algyr/tm.com.algyr.LanguageActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'tm.com.algyr.application.AlgyrAppContainer tm.com.algyr.application.AlgyrApp.appContainer' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3448)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3595)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2147)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7814)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'tm.com.algyr.application.AlgyrAppContainer tm.com.algyr.application.AlgyrApp.appContainer' on a null object reference
        at tm.com.algyr.localization.LocaleActivity.attachBaseContext(LocaleActivity.java:15)
        at android.app.Activity.attach(Activity.java:7855)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3379)
```

and application code:

```
 final public AlgyrAppContainer appContainer = new AlgyrAppContainer();

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        LocaleUtility.bypassHiddenApiRestrictions();
    }

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        appContainer.makeInitiation(base);
        super.attachBaseContext(appContainer.localeManager.setLocale(base));
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(@NotNull Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        appContainer.localeManager.setLocale(this);
    }
```

Thanks for help!)) P.S. I already searched for this issue, but didn't find anything.(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this approach, so you can make use of your custom application class instance in any part of your code via `App.instance`. Nevertheless, you should use Dagger or Koin for your DI, as it is development standard.

```
class App: Application() {
    
        override fun onCreate() {
            super.onCreate()
            instance = this
        }
        
        companion object {
            lateinit var instance: App
                private set
        }
}
```

Comment: Thx for your response, I need to try it)